# How to make my Piecewise function zero outside the provided interval in python

Tags: python, sympy

Here is my code:

```
    In [61]: import sympy as sp

    In [62]: x = sp.Symbol('x')

    In [63]: phi_1 = sp.Piecewise( ( (1.3-x)/0.3, 1<=x <=1.3 ))

    In [64]: phi_1.subs(x,1.2)
    Out[64]: 0.333333333333334

    In [65]: phi_1.subs(x,1.4)
    Out[65]: Piecewise()
```

More specifically, I want to get zero as an answer to the input no. 65, since 1.4 is outside the interval [1, 1.3].

Comment: What version of python and sympy are you using (`print(sp.__version__)`)?  With 0.7.6 on Python 2.7, [63] returns a `TypeError`.

Comment: The version is: 0.7.1.rc1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell `Piecewise` that you want the function to evaluate to zero when outside the bounds, for example:

```
import sympy as sp

x = sp.Symbol('x')

phi_1 = sp.Piecewise(
    (0, x < 1),
    (0, x > 1.3),
    ( (1.3-x)/0.3, True )
)

print(phi_1.subs(x,1.2)) # 0.333333333333334

print(phi_1.subs(x,1.4)) # 0
```

Note that this syntax works in 0.7.1 and 0.7.6 -- your code raises an `TypeError` in 0.7.6 with the "compound conditional" `1 <=x <=1.3`