# Sympy - How to solve equations with intervals in Piecewise functions?

Tags: python, sympy, intervals, piecewise

I have a list of equations, which contain elements, created by `sympy.Interval(0,1)` as following:

```
BR=[]
for i in range(len(equations)):
    BR.append(sympy.Piecewise((0, equations[i] < 0), (sympy.Interval(0,1),sympy.Eq(equations[i], 0)),
    (1,equations[i]>0)))
```

[creating a list of functions 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rwX2.png)

Then I get a list of functions, using list with symbolic variables in `h3` by following rule:

```
constr=[]
for i in range(len(h3)):
    constr.append(sympy.Eq(h3[i], BR[i]))
```

[creating a list of functions 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs3GJ.png)

So, part of my functions should be any number from 0 to 1 including, if the requirement is fulfilled at specific point. But due to using interval in the function's definition when I try `sympy.solve(constr,h3)` an error is occurring:

```
AttributeError: 'Interval' object has no attribute 'as_coeff_Mul'
```

How can I solve this system of equations?

Comment: Does this answer you question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307980/how-to-make-my-piecewise-function-zero-outside-the-provided-interval-in-python?

Comment: @RedKnite Unfortunately, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307980/how-to-make-my-piecewise-function-zero-outside-the-provided-interval-in-python) is refered to intervals as range of definition  in a function, while in this question we should cope with intervals within functions, as their parts.